# About isotopy of simple close curve

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, curves-and-surfaces, mapping-class-groups

In the Primer mapping class group by farb Margalit. We have :

**Proposition** 1.10 Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two essential simple closed curves in a surface $S$. Then $\alpha$ is isotopic to $\beta$ if and only if $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$.

Proof. One direction is vacuous since an isotopy is a homotopy. So suppose that $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$. We immediately have that $i(\alpha, \beta)=0$. By performing an isotopy of $\alpha$, we may assume that $\alpha$ is transverse to $\beta$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not disjoint, then by the bigon criterion they form a bigon. A bigon prescribes an isotopy that reduces intersection. Thus we may remove bigons one by one by isotopy until $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint.

In the remainder of the proof, we assume $\chi(S)<0$; the case $\chi(S)=0$ is similar, and the case $\chi(S)>0$ is easy. Choose lifts $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that have the same endpoints in $\partial \mathbb{H}^{2}$. There is a hyperbolic isometry $\phi$ that leaves $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ invariant and acts by translation on these lifts. As $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ are disjoint, we may consider the region $R$ between them. The quotient $R^{\prime}=$ $R /\langle\phi\rangle$ is an annulus; indeed, it is a surface with two boundary components with an infinite cyclic fundamental group. A priori, the image $R^{\prime \prime}$ of $R$ in $S$ is a further quotient of $R^{\prime}$. However, since the covering map $R^{\prime} \rightarrow R^{\prime \prime}$ is single-sheeted on the boundary, it follows that $R^{\prime} \approx R^{\prime \prime}$. The annulus $R^{\prime \prime}$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ gives the desired isotopy .

> I can't understand this proof for $\chi(S)<0$ . Is there any reference for more details for this proposition?  Or simple proof ? I read paper by "bear" in the original proof but this is more difficult.

I think we consider $ \langle \phi\rangle$ as discrate topological group acts on $R$ but why quotient $R^{\prime}=$ $R /\langle\phi\rangle$ is an annulus ? also I think
$ \langle \phi\rangle$ is isomorphic to infinite cyclic group $\mathbb Z$

Is this following shape true ?

[image]

Comment: To understand this proof you'll need at least theorem 1.2 from Farb Margalit, the classification of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^2$ (the isometry $\varphi$ the proof talks about is a hyperbolic isometry with axis the geodesic joining the endpoints of $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$), basic covering space theory and the obvious fact that if two curves are the boundary components of some annulus then they are isotopic.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín  I read this theorem.  But I can't understand why  There is a hyperbolic isometry $\phi$ that leaves $\widetilde{\alpha}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$ invariant and acts by translation on these lifts ? Why?

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín .why The quotient $R^{\prime}=$ $R /\langle\phi\rangle$ is an annulus ?

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín . What is $R /\langle\phi\rangle$ ? What is $ \langle\phi\rangle$ ?

Comment: You could try my lecture notes here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~hjrw2/RS%20lectures.pdf . I wrote an updated version in the last few months -- I have a feeling one of the updates concerns this proof -- which I'll try to post in the next few days.

Comment: @T566y65tt: Unfortunately I have commitments of my own.

Comment: @HJRW. Can you send me your lecture note ? I need proof for self learning.

Comment: I already provided the link! I may post an updated version at the same link *when I have time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ is a closed connected surface with negative Euler characteristic. Suppose that $H$ is the universal cover of $S$.  Equipping $S$ with a hyperbolic metric we find that $H$ is isometric to the hyperbolic plane.

**Exercise**: Every non-trivial deck transformation of $H$ over $S$ is *hyperbolic*: that is, has exactly two fixed points at infinity.

Suppose that $\alpha$ is a simple closed curve.  Suppose that $\alpha$ is essential: in particular it does not bound a disk in $S$.  We choose a point $x_0$ of $\alpha$ to be the basepoint of $\pi_1(S, x_0)$.  Let $y_0 \in H$ be any preimage of $x_0$.

Let $\phi : ([0, 1], \{0, 1\}) \to (S, x_0)$ be a parameterisation of $\alpha$.  Note that $[\phi]$ is an element of $\pi_1(S, x_0)$.  We lift $\phi$  via path lifting to obtain a simple arc $\phi_0 : ([0, 1], \{0, 1\}) \to (H, {y_0, y_1})$.  Note that path lifting defines the point $y_1$.  There is a unique deck transformation that takes $y_0$ to $y_1$.  In fact, this is the image of $[\phi]$ in the deck group. We will abuse notation and simply call this deck transformation $[\phi]$.

**Exercise**: $y_1$ is not equal to $y_0$.  Thus the deck transformation $[\phi]$ is a hyperbolic transformation of $H$.

Let $\langle \phi \rangle$ be the subgroup of the deck group generated by $[\phi]$.  Define $\phi_k = [\phi]^k \cdot \phi_0$.  Let $A = \cup \phi_k$ be the union of the translates of $\phi_0$.  We call $A$ an *elevation* of $\alpha$ (as it is a union of lifts giving a copy of the universal cover of $\alpha$).

**Exercise**: $A$ is a quasi-geodesic in $H$.

Thus $A$ has two endpoints in $\partial H$, the ideal boundary of $H$.

**Exercise**: Suppose that $\beta$ is a loop in $S$ that is (freely) homotopic to $\alpha$.  Then all components of the preimage of $\beta$, in $H$, are quasi-geodesics, and exactly one (call it $B$) shares the ideal endpoints of $A$.

We now require an additional hypothesis.  We must suppose that $S$ is orientable.  If we do not, then it is possible that $\alpha$ is a core curve of a Möbius band: in this case $\alpha$ meets all curves in its free homotopy class.  (You may want to think about how this interacts with the bigon criterion.)

Suppose that $\beta$ is a simple closed curve which is freely homotopic to, and disjoint from, $\alpha$. Recall that $A$ and $B$ are the chosen quasi-geodesic elevations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  We deduce that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint in $H$ and share their ideal points in $\partial H$. So they cobound an (infinite) strip $R$ in $H$.  Choose an arc $c_0$ that embeds in $R$ and connects $x_0 \in A$ to a point of $B$.

**Exercise**: We can choose $c_0$ so that it is disjoint from $c_k = [\phi]^k \cdot c_0$.

Finally, we deduce that $c_0$ and $c_1 = [\phi] \cdot c_0$ cobound a disk $D$ contained in $R$.  Thus $R / \langle \phi \rangle$ is homeomorphic to the annulus $D / (c_0 \sim c_1)$

Comment: So my shape is true ?

Comment: Neither of the pictures at the end of your post are an annulus. So, no?

Comment: Why the case $\chi(S)=0$  is similar? In this case we have euclidean surface but I don't know why we have similar way ?

Comment: Much of the argument is similar. However we will need to replace the hyperbolic geometry arguments with Euclidean ones.

Comment: is there any reference about your proof ?

Comment: There is no reference for my proof, as I made it up myself.  However, there are references for the statement you want to prove.  Of course the first reference is the Primer.  After that there is Stillwell's volume of translations of Dehn's papers "Papers on Group Theory and Topology". See the appendix "The Dehn-Nielsen Theorem".

Comment: Stillwell also gives references to the original papers of Nielsen (who, he says, attributes the main ideas to Dehn). Stillwell has also translated some of Nielsen's work.

Comment: If I have answered your question, then it is helpful (to me and to others) if you accept the answer.  You do this by clicking the "grey check mark" immediately below the up/down vote buttons.

Comment: I accept your answer but I can't understand details of proof .for example why we have same proof for $\chi (S)=0$ ? How can I find more details?

Comment: I suggest that you focus on the case $\chi(S) < 0$ and worry about the case $\chi(S) = 0$ at a future date.  The hyperbolic geometry is trickier, and will require more of your time.

Comment: Why $y_1$ is not equal to $y_0$ ? Why $\phi_0 : ([0, 1], \{0, 1\}) \to (H, {y_0, y_1})$ is simple arc ?

Comment: This is an exercise in path-lifting.  You will need to use the hypothesis that $\alpha$ is essential.  (In my post I only assumed that $\alpha$ does not bound a disk - I will fix that.)