# Essential simple closed curves in a torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Definition: By a closed curve in a surface $S$ we will mean a continuous map $S^1 \to S$.
We will usually identify a closed curve with its image in $S$. A closed curve
is called essential if it is not homotopic to a point, a puncture, or a boundary
component.

I want to prove the following lemma:

> **Lemma**. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two essential simple closed curves in a torus $T$. Then $\alpha$ is isotopic to $\beta$ if and only if $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$.

**Proof**. One direction is vacuous since an isotopy is a homotopy. So suppose that $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$. We immediately have that $i(\alpha, \beta)=0$.

Also we have:

> **Theorem**: The nontrivial homotopy classes of oriented simple closed
> curves in a torus $T$ are in bijective correspondence with the set of primitive elements of $\pi_1(T) ≈ \mathbb{Z}^2$.
> An element (p, q) of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is primitive if and only if $(p, q) = (0, \pm1)$,
> $(p, q)=(\pm1, 0)$, or $\gcd(p, q)=1$.

Comment: What is your question?  What is $i(\alpha, \beta)$?

Comment: @LSpice this is intersection number between to curve.

Comment: The proof is a modification of the one I give here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/414154/1650

Comment: Have you thought about the sketch I previously provided?  Do you have comments or questions about it?

Answer (score 1):

A detailed sketch (again requiring exercises) is given in Chapter Two, Section C (titled "Knots in the torus") of Rolfsen's book *Knots and links*.